# How to align re query output in adjacent coulmns

Tags: batch-file

This is my code

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

(   FOR /f %%a in (C:\r\input.txt) do (
        FOR /L %%s IN (1,1,1) DO SET "col%%s="
        SET col1=%%a
        echo !col1! >>info.csv
        FOR /F "tokens=1*delims= " %%G IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\ACPI"') DO (
            FOR %%H IN ("%%~G") DO >>info.csv echo %%~nxH
        )))
```

This is `input.txt`:

```
LIN35008665
```

This is `output.csv`:

```
LIN35008655
DSDT
FACS
RSDT
SSD1
```

I want the `output.csv` to look like this:

```
LIN35008655
DSDT FACS RSDT SSD1
```

Should I try with tab?

Comment: I have fixed your formatting, including your code which was invalid formatted as you had it. We have no idea what you should try with, because you have not told us the format you'd like your CSV file to be in. A CSV file does not have any columns, it is a plain text file with records made up of fields, each separated by a known delimiter, most commonly a comma, and often with a header identification record for each field.

Comment: Hi Compo,Sorry if I was not clear in the beginning. Your inputs are valuable. I am not sure what we mean by format of CSV. But I want the reg query output to be displayed in adjacent columns.  Is there anything else I can help u with.

Comment: You can tell us the format of the CSV file, there are no columns in one. Why not start by telling us what program you intend to open the CSV file with.

Comment: Your code seems to be over-complicated: 1. the `for /L` loop is completely unnecessary since it just clears variable `col1` (in a cumbersome way), which is then anyway set; 2. the `for %%H` loop is superfluous since you could simply use `%%~nxG` (instead of `%%~nxH`). What you should look for is how to echo out text without new-line (like: `< nul set /P ="some text"`), so you can build what you are calling "columns"…

Comment: @PurvaParulekar, as I said in your previous post, instead of using an echo for each iteration of the third `FOR` command, build a variable!  `FOR %%H IN ("%%~G") DO set "line=!line! %%~nxH"`.  The on a separate line after the third `FOR` command: `>>info.csv echo !line:~1!`

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your responses and help. This is my first successful code with Stackflow ,looking forward to many more. Squashman, I used ur logic this time. Thanks.

Comment: Hi have one more query regarding this, I will create a new question anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for building lists is string concatenation. The below uses a macro to build and delimit a list during for loops (Amongst other features).

demonstration script:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DLM=   "
 Set "List/A=(If "!$L:~0,1!"=="!DLM!" Set "$L=!$L:~1!")& Set "$L#=0"& For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (For %%l in (!$L!)Do (Set "$L[!$L#!]=%%l"&Set /A "$L#+=1"))Else Set $L=!$L!!DLM!"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%G IN ('reg query "\\%ComputerName%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\ACPI"') DO %List/A:$L=HardWare%%%~nG
(Echo/!HardWare!) 1>"output.csv"
```

Variable name is supplied at expansion using substring modifaction, DLM can be modified to your chosen delimiter

The above macro is overfeatured for your particular usage as it also tracks how many items are appended to the list as well as defines the list values to an array.

The minimal version for your needs that could replace the definition of `List/A` above is:

```bat
 Set "List/A=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (If "!$L:~0,1!"=="!DLM!" Set "$L=!$L:~1!")Else Set $L=!$L!!DLM!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your limited, information and clarity, my suggestion would be for `output.csv` to contain records with `C`omma `S`eparated `V`alue fields. e.g. `"LIN35008655","DSDT","FACS","RSDT","SSD1"`

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(   For /F UseBackQDelims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("C:\r\input.txt") Do (
        For /F "Tokens=2 Delims={}" %%H In ('^"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe^
         /Node:"%%G" Class StdRegProv Call EnumKey "&H80000002"^,^
         "HARDWARE\ACPI" 2^> NUL ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" "sNames"^"'
        ) Do Set "_=%%H" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo "%%G",!_:", "=","!& EndLocal)) 1> "output.csv"
```

---

If you still wanted that non CSV data inside a file with a `.csv` extension, you'd simply make a small modification.

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(   For /F UseBackQDelims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("C:\r\input.txt") Do (
        For /F "Tokens=2 Delims={}" %%H In ('^"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe^
         /Node:"%%G" Class StdRegProv Call EnumKey "&H80000002"^,^
         "HARDWARE\ACPI" 2^> NUL ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" "sNames"^"'
        ) Do Set "_=%%H" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Echo %%G
        Set "_=!_:", "=" "!" & Echo !_:^"=!& EndLocal)) 1> "output.csv"
```